# add row in table; if a code is duplicated or a code is not present then message is to be shown & row not added

Tags: sql, mysql

```
CREATE TABLE EMP (
        ECODE char(16) PRIMARY KEY,  
        ENAME char(20),
        DCODE char(16),
        GRADE char(1),
        BASIC int,
        JN_DT Date
);

CREATE TABLE DEPT (
    DCODE char(16) PRIMARY KEY,
    DNAME char(20)
);

INSERT INTO EMP VALUES 
('E1','AAA','D1','A','9000','2007-05-07'),
('E2','BBB','D2', 'B','6000','2010-01-02'),
('E3','CCC','D3', 'C','8000','2017-07-17'),
('E4','DDD','D1','A','5000','2014-01-14'),
('E5','EEE','D2','A','7000','2006-05-13'),
('E6','FFF','D1','B','9000','2003-11-09');

INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES 
('D1','XXX'),
('D2','YYY'),
('D3','ZZZ');
```

> Write a MySQL block to add row in the EMP table. If employee code is duplicated or the dept code is not present in the DEPT table then a message is to be shown & the row cannot be added.

Running it as a block is more difficult in higher versions of MySQL.

How do I do this?

Comment: Since `ECODE` is the primary key, you'll get an error if you try to insert a duplicate.

Comment: Declare `EMP.DCODE` as a foreign key to `DEPT.DCODE`. You'll get an error if you try to use a dept code that isn't in `DEPT`.

Comment: the op asks for the code block!

Comment: 'Running it as a block is more difficult in higher versions of MySQL.' - ??what do you mean by this. If you have code you should publish it together with any error messages.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below Block:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE emp_code_count INT;
    DECLARE dept_code_count INT;
    
    SET emp_code_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMP WHERE ECODE = 'EMPLOYEE_CODE_TO_BE_INSERTED');
    SET dept_code_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DEPT WHERE DCODE = 'DEPARTMENT_CODE_TO_BE_INSERTED');
    
    IF emp_code_count > 0 THEN
        SELECT 'Duplicate employee code found. Row cannot be added.';
    ELSEIF dept_code_count = 0 THEN
        SELECT 'Department code not found in DEPT table. Row cannot be added.';
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO EMP (ECODE, ENAME, DCODE, GRADE, BASIC, JN_DT) 
        VALUES ('EMPLOYEE_CODE_TO_BE_INSERTED', 'EMPLOYEE_NAME', 'DEPARTMENT_CODE_TO_BE_INSERTED', 'EMPLOYEE_GRADE', EMPLOYEE_BASIC_SALARY, 'EMPLOYEE_JOINING_DATE');
        SELECT 'Row added successfully.';
    END IF;
END;
```

To execute this block, you can use any MySQL client or MySQL command-line interface and execute the entire block at once. Remember to replace the placeholders with actual values before running the block.

This block first checks if the employee code already exists in the EMP table. If it does, it returns a message indicating that a duplicate employee code was found, and the row is not added. If the employee code is unique, it then checks if the department code exists in the DEPT table. If the department code is not found, it returns a message indicating that the department code was not found, and the row is not added. Finally, if both the employee code and department code are valid, it inserts the row into the EMP table and returns a success message.

Comment: 'You can use below Block:' - only in a stored routine..mysql does not support anonymous code blocks.